# How to write/read own summary details to file properties in Delphi?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe3, file-properties

Most popular files (Like Word documents, TXT files, JPG images,...) have their specific summary details fields in properties.

my program generates its save file, is it possible to have my own summary details fields in properties for my generated file? i searched over the internet but i just found articles and codes about read/write details of those common files (Word Documents, ID3 Tag of mp3 files,...)

[image]

Comment: It's driven by the Windows Property System. Documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff728898(v=vs.85).aspx